# Downgrading mybatis version from 3.2.2 to 3.0.4 makes executed sql statements to disapper in log file

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, mybatis

**Action performed:**
In my maven project/module, recently I tried downgrading mybatis version for compatibility with other modules. I downgraded mybatis version from ***mybatis-3.2.2*** to ***mybatis-3.0.4.***

**Issue:**
With mybatis-3.2.2, the executing sql statements were showing up in the log file. After the downgrade, executing sql statements are not showing up in the log file. 

**Question:** Just switching the mybatis jar is causing the executing sql statements logs to disappear, Am I missing something here?

Following are the jars relevant to the issue in the project:

```
1) jdk1.6.0_45
2) mybatis-3.0.4.jar 
3) slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
4) slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
5) log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Log file: (This is the first statement in the log file showing adapter being used)

```
2016-10-19 13:07:44,461 DEBUG  [LogFactory] Logging initialized using 'org.apache.ibatis.logging.slf4j.Slf4jImpl' adapter.
```

log4j.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="File" value="C:\\Job\\job.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

     <logger name="org.quartz" additivity="false">
         <level value="ERROR"/>
     </logger>

    <logger name="java.sql" additivity="false">
       <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

log4j.properties (properties file also exists in the project, to my knowledge log4j.xml file would preferred over this properties file)

```
# Global logging configuration
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
# SqlMap logging configuration...
log4j.logger.com.ibatis=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] - %m%n
```

log4j.dtd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!-- Authors: Chris Taylor, Ceki Gulcu. -->

<!-- Version: 1.2 -->

<!-- A configuration element consists of optional renderer
elements,appender elements, categories and an optional root
element. -->

<!ELEMENT log4j:configuration (renderer*, appender*,(category|logger)*,root?,
                               categoryFactory?)>

<!-- The "threshold" attribute takes a level value such that all -->
<!-- logging statements with a level equal or below this value are -->
<!-- disabled. -->

<!-- Setting the "debug" enable the printing of internal log4j logging   -->
<!-- statements.                                                         -->

<!-- By default, debug attribute is "null", meaning that we not do touch -->
<!-- internal log4j logging settings. The "null" value for the threshold -->
<!-- attribute can be misleading. The threshold field of a repository    -->
<!-- cannot be set to null. The "null" value for the threshold attribute -->
<!-- simply means don't touch the threshold field, the threshold field   --> 
<!-- keeps its old value.                                                -->

<!ATTLIST log4j:configuration
  xmlns:log4j              CDATA #FIXED "http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" 
  threshold                (all|debug|info|warn|error|fatal|off|null) "null"
  debug                    (true|false|null)  "null"
>

<!-- renderer elements allow the user to customize the conversion of  -->
<!-- message objects to String.                                       -->

<!ELEMENT renderer EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST renderer
  renderedClass  CDATA #REQUIRED
  renderingClass CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!-- Appenders must have a name and a class. -->
<!-- Appenders may contain an error handler, a layout, optional parameters -->
<!-- and filters. They may also reference (or include) other appenders. -->
<!ELEMENT appender (errorHandler?, param*, layout?, filter*, appender-ref*)>
<!ATTLIST appender
  name      ID  #REQUIRED
  class     CDATA   #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT layout (param*)>
<!ATTLIST layout
  class     CDATA   #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT filter (param*)>
<!ATTLIST filter
  class     CDATA   #REQUIRED
>

<!-- ErrorHandlers can be of any class. They can admit any number of -->
<!-- parameters. -->

<!ELEMENT errorHandler (param*, root-ref?, logger-ref*,  appender-ref?)> 
<!ATTLIST errorHandler
   class        CDATA   #REQUIRED 
>

<!ELEMENT root-ref EMPTY>

<!ELEMENT logger-ref EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST logger-ref
  ref IDREF #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT param EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST param
  name      CDATA   #REQUIRED
  value     CDATA   #REQUIRED
>


<!-- The priority class is org.apache.log4j.Level by default -->
<!ELEMENT priority (param*)>
<!ATTLIST priority
  class   CDATA #IMPLIED
  value   CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!-- The level class is org.apache.log4j.Level by default -->
<!ELEMENT level (param*)>
<!ATTLIST level
  class   CDATA #IMPLIED
  value   CDATA #REQUIRED
>


<!-- If no level element is specified, then the configurator MUST not -->
<!-- touch the level of the named category. -->
<!ELEMENT category (param*,(priority|level)?,appender-ref*)>
<!ATTLIST category
  class         CDATA   #IMPLIED
  name      CDATA   #REQUIRED
  additivity    (true|false) "true"  
>

<!-- If no level element is specified, then the configurator MUST not -->
<!-- touch the level of the named logger. -->
<!ELEMENT logger (level?,appender-ref*)>
<!ATTLIST logger
  name      ID  #REQUIRED
  additivity    (true|false) "true"  
>


<!ELEMENT categoryFactory (param*)>
<!ATTLIST categoryFactory 
   class        CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT appender-ref EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST appender-ref
  ref IDREF #REQUIRED
>

<!-- If no priority element is specified, then the configurator MUST not -->
<!-- touch the priority of root. -->
<!-- The root category always exists and cannot be subclassed. -->
<!ELEMENT root (param*, (priority|level)?, appender-ref*)>


<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!--                       A logging event                                -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!ELEMENT log4j:eventSet (log4j:event*)>
<!ATTLIST log4j:eventSet
  xmlns:log4j             CDATA #FIXED "http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" 
  version                (1.1|1.2) "1.2" 
  includesLocationInfo   (true|false) "true"
>



<!ELEMENT log4j:event (log4j:message, log4j:NDC?, log4j:throwable?, 
                       log4j:locationInfo?) >

<!-- The timestamp format is application dependent. -->
<!ATTLIST log4j:event
    logger     CDATA #REQUIRED
    level      CDATA #REQUIRED
    thread     CDATA #REQUIRED
    timestamp  CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT log4j:message (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT log4j:NDC (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT log4j:throwable (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT log4j:locationInfo EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST log4j:locationInfo
  class  CDATA  #REQUIRED
  method CDATA  #REQUIRED
  file   CDATA  #REQUIRED
  line   CDATA  #REQUIRED
>
```